# Lighthouse reporting is failing in Jenkins with below error

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, lighthouse

> ```
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:18 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.............................................................................................
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:19 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...............................................................................................
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:19 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.................................................................................................
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:20 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser...................................................................................................
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:20 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.....................................................................................................
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:21 GMT ChromeLauncher Waiting for browser.......................................................................................................
>
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:21 GMT ChromeLauncher:error connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:36157
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:21 GMT ChromeLauncher:error Logging contents of /tmp/lighthouse.mOZ6RIf/chrome-err.log
> Fri, 28 May 2021 09:27:21 GMT ChromeLauncher:error Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 86: unknown element "blank"
> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../elf/dl-tls.c: 488: _dl_allocate_tls_init: Assertion `listp->slotinfo[cnt].gen <= GL(dl_tls_generation)' failed!
>
> Unable to connect to Chrome
> 370/0: Lighthouse analysis FAILED for https://website.com/en/....
> rm: no such file or directory: report/lighthouse/website/en....report.json
>
> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/lighthouse-batch/index.js:219
>    const score = toScore(summary.detail.performance)
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'performance' of undefined
>    at checkBudgets (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/lighthouse-batch/index.js:219:42)
>    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/lighthouse-batch/index.js:67:20
>    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
>    at execute (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/lighthouse-batch/index.js:39:38)
>    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/lighthouse-batch/run.js:28:1)
>    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
>    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
>    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
>    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! Lighthouse_Reports@1.0.0 lighthouse: `lighthouse-batch -f sites.txt -p --config-path=config.js -h --performance 75 --score 70 --no-report –chrome-flags='–headless','--no-sandbox'`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> ```

I'm running this report for 900+ page urls.

Answer (score 0):

As the logs tell, ChromeLauncher is refusing connection to Jenkins. You might want to check if Jenkins is allowed to access this running service.

This can also happen if your ChromeLauncher is **not** running in **headless** mode, or multiple instances of ChromeLauncher are running, and no available ports for it are left.

You can try adding the following to you ChromeLauncher launch configs. In fact, you should mention these.

```
chromeOptions = {
        chromeFlags: ["--disable-gpu", "--headless", "--enable-logging"] 
}
```

Find more details to this [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/2462).

As an alternative, you can consider running **Lighthouse** in a Docker instead, to isolate it from Jenkins. This way, you can scan your project, generate HTML reports and publish it back to Jenkins.

You can follow the approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/main/docs/recipes/docker-server/README.md).

Comment: thanks for your response, I was using '-headless' flag already and tried with those flags you mentioned, but still facing the same issue. I think, I should try docker approach. Is there any limitation with no.of page URLs we can run on for this lighthouse report?

Comment: @rajumuddana As far as I know, there is no such limitation. Just make sure there isn't some official limitation imposed in the open-source version.